# I'd like to connect the values of my attributes to the value on my sliders in a GUI but I keep on getting an attribute error

Tags: python, class, user-interface, pyqt5, vpython

I'm creating a GUI for a planetary orbit simulator and would like to allow the user to control the features of the planets using sliders, check boxes, etc. When I try to change the values using the GUI I get an attribute error.

Right now I have a function called changePlanet which is supposed to set the value of the slider as the attribute of the object when a planet is selected. The code below is an example of this.

```
self.which_planet.activated.connect(self.changePlanet)
```

So when planet 1 is selected it activates the changePlanet Function:

```
def changePlanet(self,p):
        planet = self.which_planet.currentText()

        if planet == "Planet 1":
            self.slider1.setValue(p.p1.radius)
            self.colors.setId(p.p1.color)
            self.slider2.setValue(p.p1.mass)
            self.x_slider.setValue(p.p1.x)
            self.y_slider.setValue(p.p1.y)
            self.z_slider.setValue(p.p1.z)
```

The output when I try to run this is an attribute error, does anyone know why?

Comment: Please post a minimal example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Because `p` is a python `bool` object, which doesn't have a `p1` attribute.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you, what would I do to fix this.

Comment: @Moselle What is `p` and where does it come from? It looks like you expect it to be passed to `changePlanet`, but how?

Comment: Can you post the full `AttributeError` exception you're getting? It's very difficult to say where the problem is without any information.

Comment: Hey, ive imported my class planet as p in this document as it i saved in another file.

Comment: The error i get is AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'p1'

Comment: @Moselle In that case, all you need to do is change the method definition to this: `def changePlanet(self):`. Because otherwise, the argument name will shadow the imported name.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you so much its working now!!!